# Yii's CCompareValidator doesn't work

Tags: php, yii, validation

Either I don't understand how [CCompareValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCompareValidator/) works in Yii (sic!) or it doesn't work for me at all.

I want to check, if an ID of row / record / user being updated isn't the same, as an ID of currently logged-in user. And prohibit update, if it is.

I used `CCompareValidator` at first:

```
array('id', 'compare', 'compareValue'=>Yii::app()->user->id, 'message'=>'Boom!')
```

It doesn't work -- it halts editing / update of every row / record / user, no matter, what an ID actually is.

So, I rewrote it to my own, custom validator. In my opinion, the code is the same as in case of built-in one:

```
array('id', 'compareId', 'compareValue'=>Yii::app()->user->id, 'message'=>'Boom!')

public function compareId($attribute = null, $params = null)
{
    if($attribute === 'id')
    {
        if($this->id == $params['compareValue'])
        {
            $this->addError($params['message']);
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm -- allows update of any row / record / user, which ID is different than currently logged-in user's ID. Blocks update, showing defined message, in case compared IDs are equal.

What am I missing? Why original Yii's built in validator fails on such simple example, while my own works?

Comment: Do you set `skipOnError` false?

Comment: [`skipOnError`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#skipOnError-detail) is set to `false` by default. And beside, it has nothing to do with this problem -- it deals with situation, where there are more than one validation error, and in this case, this is first and the only validation error. To make myself sure, I tested the case with both `skipOnError` set to `true` and `false`. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator works, as supposed, my logic have failed:

1. `CCompareValidator`, throws an error, when two compared values **are not equal**. On the other hand, if they're equal -- it passes validation without errors. That is supposed behavior.
2. I wanted an error, when values are equal (which means, that user is attempting to edit himself or herself) and pass as validated, when both values are different (logged user edits different one).

That's why I need to use `'operator'=>'!='` as configuration of validator. This is the answer.

BTW: All the glory of solving this problem goes to [Keith at YiiFramework.com's forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52963-ccomparevalidator-isnt-working-as-supposed/page__view__findpost__p__244334).